# Vue Data Object Limitations

Tags: vue.js, memory, memory-management, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to figure out how much is too much data to store in a Vue data object.

Say I have 4,000+ objects like this:

```
personWithAppointment = {
  id: 1,
  appointment_id: 1,
  first_name: 'Jim',
  last_name: 'Jim',
  // +20 more similar attributes
}
```

And I've stored those objects in my *peopleWithAppointments* data object in Vue:

```
data() {
  peopleWithAppointments: [
    // 4,000 personWithAppointment objects
  ],
}
```

Is this too much data? Are 10K results too much? What about 50K? Is there a way for me to tell?

What about if I've stored this data in my Vuex store's state instead?

Answer (score -1):

There is no limitation but there is no sense to keep 10k objects in vue.
Strongly recommended to move it to any DB like MongoDB.

Comment: I'm fetching the data from an API and rendering a list. I then have click events that fetch more data when clicking on one of those list items. I updated my question a bit as I think the _people_ example may have been misleading. I'm just trying to figure out if I end up fetching 4K, 10K, etc. results, am I going to have issues having that list of objects sitting in the data object. If I were to find out that storing thousands and thousands of results in the Vue object isn't concerning, I'm going to create a paginated list and output those results.